# Make one Summernote working for all textarea without repeating,

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, summernote

I have multiple Textarea tags in my page and i need only one Summernote fixed on the top of the page that will work for every textarea.

```
[<div class="kt-container kt-container--fluid kt-grid__item kt-grid__item--fluid">
    <div class="kt-portlet kt-portlet--mobile">
        <span class="summernote" style="margin-botton:65px;"></span>
    </div>
</div>][1]
```

I'm using repeater where onclick add new row button will add new texterea. I need to make summernote working for every textarea.

`<tr><td colspan='6'><textarea class="summernote" name='description[]' cols='30' rows='5'></textarea></td></tr>`

Here I'm initializing the summernote.

```
    $('.summernote').summernote({
      placeholder: 'item Descr...'
    });
```

Comment: please include what you tried so far , with a small snippet, what doesn't work if tried , and what are the expected results ...  thanks

Comment: I have added the code and view of the page. Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish. Can you share more of your code? What do you mean "only one Summernote fixed on the top of the page"?